# Why shmat() of aio-stress.c in LTP uses a non-null shmaddr, 0x50000000?

Tags: c, shared-memory

[shmat() in aio-stress.c](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/a161c6f88b4ac092cfd4796e502206a5543dada5/testcases/kernel/io/ltp-aiodio/aio-stress.c#L1031) uses a non-null shmaddr 0x50000000. This looks like very peculiar. Where does the address come from? Why the author can be sure this address can be used?

Comment: Based on the comments I see no need for the fixed address and I'm guessing it's just bogus. It's certainly not valid to assume that address is untaken.

Comment: No. Looks like the shmaddr 0x50000000 works just fine. It's not bogus.

Comment: The fact that it happens to work on your system has no bearing on whether it's valid.